# Wordpress Query for CPT that only shows posts within radius of current user's geolocation

Tags: wp-query, location-search

I have a CPT called medical_providers. Each medical provider has two ACF meta_fields (latitude and longitude). I want to write a wp_query to only show medical providers that are within a certain range (100 miles?) of the current user's IP address. Here is my query so far. It does not include anything related to geolocation.

```
   <?php
                        $paged = ( get_query_var('paged') ) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
                        global $wp_query;
                        $original_query = $wp_query;
                        $args = array(
                            'post_type' => 'medical_provider',
                            'posts_per_page' => 12,
                            'paged' => $paged,
                            'post_status' => 'publish',
                           'meta_key'           => 'is_preferred',
                         'orderby'          => 'meta_value',
                         'order'                => 'DESC',
                        );
                        
                        $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
                        $wp_query = $the_query;
                        if ( $the_query->have_posts()) :
                            while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); 
                                get_template_part( 'template-parts/medical-provider-content-post' );
                            endwhile;
                            ?>
```

Comment: Note that this is going to be an **extremely heavy** database query, you will want to limit the number of times this query runs and cache the results at every available opportunity. Having more than 2 people run this query could down the DB. Also IP geolocation is extremely unreliable, I spent my childhood showing up in the USA despite being in the UK because my parents chose AOL, and Google Maps regularly thinks I'm several hundred km away in Glasgow. Also you won't be able to use page cache either. It would be easier to ask the user for their location, get GPS via JS, or allow them to search

Comment: Thank you for this! I've implemented zip code search already. Is there a good resource you could point me to to get GPS via JS and display within a radius on the front end?

Comment: I don't have one, but using location services on the frontend is a common browser API, that would not be a WordPress question. You could then either request via AJAX or incorporate the latitude/longitude into the URL. Just keep in mind that unless you create buckets and shortcuts to optimise performance, you will need either a dedicated table set up for latitude/longitude storage, or something like elastic search in order to keep this performant and fast. In some situations it may even be fastest to just load everything and then do the distance math in JS